# How does partial with respect to $y(x)$ cancel an integral with respect to $dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations

$$y(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... a_M x_M$$

Textbook states by using the "calculus of the variations" the following is true:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y(x)}   \int \int (y(x) - t)^2 p(x,t)~ dt~ dx ~~~~~~~~(1)$$

$$=2 \int (y(x)-t)~p(x,t)~ dt = 0~~~~~~(2)$$

How does partial with respect to y(x) remove the integral with respect to dx?
What are the detailed steps between (1) and (2)?

I can already understand partial of

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y(x)}(y(x)-t)^2 = 2(y(x)-t)$$

I just can't figure out how the integral $\int ... dx$ gets removed when the partial is with respect to y(x).

shouldn't it be something like:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y(x)}   \int \int (y(x) - t)^2 p(x,t)~ dt~ dx$$

$$z=y(x)$$

$$dz=y'(x)dx$$

$$dx = \frac{1}{y'(x)}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}   \int \int (z - t)^2 p(x,t)~\frac{1}{y'(x)} dt ~dz$$

$$=2 \int (z - t)~ p(x,t)~\frac{1}{y'(x)} dt$$
???

Comment: its really, $LHS=0$.  so the 1 / y'(x) term disappears from  LHS when multiplying both sides by y'(x)...